# Identifying a device accessing an html page

Tags: security, html, web-applications

**The goal:**
Limit access to authorized devices who access my HTML5(.html) webapp.

**Here's the dilemma:**
I have an HTML5 Offline app(.html) that will load all of its resources from a web accessible URL. I want to restrict access to specified devices.

**The problem:**

- Identifying the device. Since .html pages cannot retrieve the mac
  address of the device, and if the user could specify the mac address
  it could easily be forged.
- Since all of the devices will be the same(iPads). User-Agent would not allow me to uniquely identify the device and it could always be faked.

Is there anyway to identify a device by a unique value within Webkit/Safari that can not be forged easily? Mac address would be the ideal value to get, but since this is not possible I am looking for any other ideas that would help identify a device uniquely.

**In a perfect world**, the device would load the webapp, the webapp would make an ajax request to the CMS to validate the unique identifier of the device and return the result.

Any ideas or thoughts are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I was just thinking a possibility would be to jailbreak the device and then use/code a native app to modify safari's user agent to include the devices macaddress, and then send that value for validation upon loading, however I doubt the customer will want to jailbreak all of their devices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best solution here would be to deploy mutually-authenticated SSL between your client tablets and your server. You can use self-signed certificates here so you don't need to buy any from a CA. This will ensure that your server only accepts requests from tablets that have the client-side certificate (configure your server to only accept the self-signed client certificates deployed on your tablets for client authentication).

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be done on the server side. The web client (browser) sends a request to the server with it's details. Now you could do it with javascipt

```
var browser = navigator.appName;
if (browser == "bad") window.location = "http://example.com";
```

but the device has to load and execute the code.

The best way would be to use PHP

```
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if ($browser == "bad") header ("Location: http://example.com");
```

but either way you do it it is always possible to give false details since you supply the information in the request.